# move multiple images from one canvas to other canvas

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

There is an example given at http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/january/an-example-of-html5-canvas-drag-n-drop.html

I am not able to add multiple images into canvas 1 and move those added images to canvas 2. Also I should be able to drag(move the added image within canvas 2) those added images in second canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses the KineticJS library to accomplish your need.

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/bSpBF/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px;}
    #container1,#container2{
      border:solid 1px #ccc;
      margin-top: 10px;
      width:300px;
      height:100px;
    }
    #container2{
      height:300px;
    }
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var highlightWidth=8;

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container1',
        width: 300,
        height: 100
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);


    var dropzone = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container2',
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    });
    var dropLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    dropzone.add(dropLayer);


    // these must go after the creation of stages & layers
    addBackground(stage,layer,dropLayer);
    layer.draw();
    addBackground(dropzone,dropLayer,layer);
    dropLayer.draw();


    // get images & then trigger start()
    var images={};
    var URLs = {
      house1: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house204-3.jpg',
      house2: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house204-4.jpg',
      house3: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house204-1.jpg'
    };
    loadImages(URLs,start);


    function start(){
        var house1=kImage(images.house1,10,10,50,50,layer);
        var house2=kImage(images.house2,75,10,50,50,layer);
        var house3=kImage(images.house3,140,10,50,50,layer);
        layer.draw();
    }


    function swapStagesIfSelected(sourceLayer,destinationLayer,startX,startY){

        // get all elements on the source layer
        var elements=sourceLayer.get("Image");

        // don't let dropped elements fall off the stage
        var totalWidth=0;
        var maxHeight=-999;
        var layerWidth=destinationLayer.getStage().getWidth();
        var layerHeight=destinationLayer.getStage().getHeight();
        for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
            if(elements[i].isSelected){
                totalWidth+=elements[i].getWidth();
                maxHeight=Math.max(elements[i].getHeight(),maxHeight);
            }
        }
        if(startX+totalWidth>layerWidth){
            startX=layerWidth-totalWidth-15; 
        }
        if(startY+maxHeight>layerHeight){
            startY=layerHeight-maxHeight-15; 
        }

        // move all selected images 
        // to the clicked x/y of the destination layer
        for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
            var element=elements[i];
            if(element.isSelected){
                var img=element.getImage();
                kImage(img,startX,startY,element.getWidth(),element.getHeight(),destinationLayer);
                startX+=element.getWidth()+10;
                element.remove();
            }
        }
        sourceLayer.draw();
        destinationLayer.draw();
    }


    // build the specified KineticJS Image and add it to the specified layer
    function kImage(image,x,y,width,height,theLayer){
        var image=new Kinetic.Image({
            image:image,
            x:x,
            y:y,
            width:width,
            height:height,
            strokeWidth:0.1,
            stroke:"green",
            draggable:true
        });
        image.myLayer=theLayer;
        image.isSelected=false;
        image.on("click",function(){
            highlight(this);
            this.myLayer.draw();
        });
        image.myLayer.add(image);
        return(image);
    }


    // build a background image and add it to the specified stage
    function addBackground(theStage,theLayer,otherLayer){

        var background = new Kinetic.Rect({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          width: theStage.getWidth(),
          height: theStage.getHeight(),
          fill: "white",
          stroke: "green",
          strokeWidth: 1
        });
        background.on("click",function(){
            var pos=theStage.getMousePosition();
            var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
            var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
            swapStagesIfSelected(otherLayer,theLayer,mouseX,mouseY);
        });
        theLayer.add(background);
    }


    /////////////  Image loader

          function loadImages(URLs, callback) {
            var loaded = 0;
            var needed = 0;
            for(var url in URLs) { needed++; console.log(url); }
            for(var url in URLs) {
              images[url] = new Image();
              images[url].onload = function() {
                if(++loaded >= needed) {
                  callback(images);
                }
              };
              images[url].src = URLs[url];
            }
          }

    /////////////  Toggle Highlighting

    function highlight(element,setStrokeWidth){
        if(setStrokeWidth){
                element.setStrokeWidth(setStrokeWidth);
        }else{
            if(element.getStrokeWidth()>5){
                element.setStrokeWidth(0.1);
                element.isSelected=false;
            }else{
                element.setStrokeWidth(highlightWidth);
                element.isSelected=true;
            }
        }
    }


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <p>Click on image(s) to toggle selection</p>
    <p>Then click in the other canvas to drop</p>
    <div id="container1"></div>
    <div id="container2"></div>
    <button id="clear">Clear Hightlights</button>
    <button id="swap">Swap Selected</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function dragDrop(e, ui) {
// get the drop point (be sure to adjust for border)
var x = parseInt(ui.offset.left - offsetX) - 1;
var y = parseInt(ui.offset.top - offsetY);

// get the drop payload (here the payload is the $tools index)
var theIndex = ui.draggable.data("toolsIndex");
// drawImage at the drop point using the dropped image 
ctx.drawImage($tools[theIndex], x, y, 32, 32);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cyur7/

This jsfiddle link is working fine.

Comment: How to enable drag and drop in other canvas also. And it was not working in my Chrome browser.

Comment: I'm using Firefox and It's fine, try other browsers don't block. To enable drag and drop you just add TheOtherCanvasName.droppable({...});